# Pass model (linq) result into pre declared variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I would like to declare a model variable (which I believe is an enumerable list of the model and then set the results to that variable.

Instead of doing this...

```
if (bIncludeGlobal)
                {
                    //include records on GLOBAL no-call
                     var model = (
                     from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                     where ((p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode || p.ProjectCode == "GLOBAL") && p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                     orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                     select p).ToList().Take(100);
                    if (model.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        return View(model);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { phonenumber = psPhoneNumber });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var model = (
                     from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                     where (p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode &&  p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                     orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                     select p).ToList().Take(100);
                    if (model.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        return View(model);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { phonenumber = psPhoneNumber });
                    }
                }
```

I'd like to do something like this... (basically declaring the model variable before the linq statement)

```
    if (bIncludeGlobal)
var model; //NOT SURE HOW TO DECLARE THIS
                    {
                        //include records on GLOBAL no-call
                         model = (
                         from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                         where ((p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode || p.ProjectCode == "GLOBAL") && p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                         orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                         select p).ToList().Take(100);
                                            }
                    else
                    {
                        var model = (
                         from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                         where (p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode &&  p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                         orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                         select p).ToList().Take(100);
                                            }
if (model.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            return View(model);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Create", new { phonenumber = psPhoneNumber });
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var model = (bIncludeGlobal)
             ? (from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                 where ((p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode || p.ProjectCode == "GLOBAL") && p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                 orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                 select p).ToList().Take(100)
             : (from p in dbMaster.tblNoCallLists
                 where (p.ProjectCode == SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode &&  p.MRN.Contains(psMRN))
                 orderby (p.AutoNumber) descending
                 select p).ToList().Take(100);

return (model.Count() > 0)
           ? View(model)
           : RedirectToAction("Create", new { phonenumber = psPhoneNumber });
```